# how to delay C# copying image from picturebox

Tags: c#, delay, picturebox

i have 2 picutreboxes and i am copying image loaded into one to another but my code is too slow in copying and when i remove the `Refresh();` it appears without any delay and I want to make the delay faster than it is with the refresh

Here's the code

```
    private void buttonClone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (pictureBoxSourcePicture.Image == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No pictuer loaded");
            return;
        }
        Bitmap clonePic = new Bitmap(pictureBoxSourcePicture.Image.Width, pictureBoxSourcePicture.Image.Height);
        Bitmap sourcePic = new Bitmap(pictureBoxSourcePicture.Image);

        for (int x = 0; x < pictureBoxSourcePicture.Image.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < pictureBoxSourcePicture.Image.Height; y++)
          {

              clonePic.SetPixel(x, y, sourcePic.GetPixel(x, y));
              pictureBoxTarget.Image = clonePic;
              pictureBoxTarget.Refresh();
              //pictureBoxSourcePicture.Image.Clone();
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code seems unnecessarily heavy - why not use `pictureBoxTarget.Image = pictureBoxSourcePicture.Image.Clone()`?

Comment: Are you trying to make it like an animation? If yes use a timer or Thread.Sleep(100) in the inner loop

Comment: Rather than have the Refresh in the inner loop, move it to the outer loop, that will speed it up a little bit.  What is your end goal here?  Are you wanting to show the picture being copied pixel by pixel?

Comment: 1st of all thanks all 4 your help, i tried to move the Refresh in the inner loop and it worked like a charm , and yes i am tried to make it like ananimation and now i don't want a timer it don't work well on high  Resolution images , and my goal is to see the processing of coping the image from picture box to the other one ,,, any way this was my 1st topic in this site and i already liked it so thanks all 4 Your contribution <3 all :D